# Transition vueJS3 v-show not working like in vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-transitions

I'm transitionning form vue 2 to vue 3.
And I have issues with Transition.

In vue 2 this transition was working but now the transition works only for the mouseleave

```vue
<template>
  <div
    @mouseover="hover = true"
    @mouseleave="hover = false"
    class="itemGallery"
  >
    <img :src="'../img/' + img[0].src" :alt="img[0].alt" />
    <Transition duration="1000" name="nested">
      <div v-show="hover" class="infos">
        <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
        <div class="tags">
          <p v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag">{{ tag }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried to change the v-show to a v-if but thad didn't change anything.
I also know that display flex can have an impact on it. But when i added an other div without a dispay proprety just for the v-show (i tried also with a v-if), nothing different appended.

I am a bit lost now, do you have some idees for me ?

This is the code of the entire component :

```vue
<template>
  <div
    @mouseover="hover = true"
    @mouseleave="hover = false"
    class="itemGallery"
  >
    <img :src="'../img/' + img[0].src" :alt="img[0].alt" />
    <Transition duration="1000" name="nested">
      <div v-show="hover" class="infos">
        <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
        <div class="tags">
          <p v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag">{{ tag }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CardPage",
  components: {},
  props: {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    img: { type: Array, required: true },
    tags: { type: Array, required: true },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      hover: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  beforeMount() {},
};
</script>
  
<style scoped>
.itemGallery {
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 26vw;
  height: 20vw;
  /* height: 26vw; */
  background-color: var(--background-color-secondary);
  margin: 1.5vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.itemGallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
  opacity: 0.9;
}
/* 
.itemGallery:hover img {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 0.5;
} */

.infos {
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.itemGallery h2 {
  font-family: "PRIMETIME", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: var(--accent-color-hover);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 4rem;
}

.tags {
  background-color: var(--accent-color-hover);
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tags p {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.nested-enter-active,
.nested-leave-active {
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}

.nested-enter-from,
.nested-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-50rem);
  opacity: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .itemGallery {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 35vw;
    margin: 2vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .itemGallery {
    width: 85vw;
    height: 70vw;
    margin: 6vw 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: What exactly "not works", the hover variable stay false? The transition not run?

And the v-if remove from the dom the element, when you use v-show it only hide it. You can inspect the element in your document and see the behaviour.

Comment: The code looks like it works ok when I use it in [Vue Playground](https://shorturl.at/fnNOU).  I only replaced img with div since there is no image file to use in the Playground environment, and I added default prop value to test with.  Do you have any errors in your console?  Can you add more code to make it reproducible?